# Check TYPO3 link type in fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I want to render a typolink in fluid, but i need to check if it is a download file (t3://file?uid=1), a page link (t3://page?uid=1) or an external link (https://www.abc.de _blank).
Is there a way or viewhelper to check the linktype in fluid?

What i found were only via typoscript or a hacky way with VHS like

```
<f:if condition="{target -> v:math.round()} > 0">
```

It's for TYPO3 9.x

Comment: Why not use `<f:link.typolink parameter="...">`? This can handle all 3 types.

Comment: Yes, but i need a condition, because i will render a download differently than a page or external page. f:link.typolink is no option.

Comment: You could already enrich the data model by an additional flag. Always thinking of a ViewHelper in first place, not only tends contradict the separation of MVC. It often also causes more work to do, just because of not applying the advantages of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ViewHelper i am using now:

```
/**
 * A view helper for rendering the linktype
 *
 * = Examples =
 *
 * <code>
 * {nc:linkType(parameter: link)}
 * </code>
 * <output>
 * page, file, url, email, folder, unknown
 * </output>
 */
class LinkTypeViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    /**
     * Initialize arguments
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        $this->registerArgument('parameter', 'string', 'stdWrap.typolink style parameter string', true);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return string Linktype (page, file, url, email, folder, unknown)
     */
    public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
    {
        $parameter = $arguments['parameter'];

        // workaround if parameter has _blank or other additional params
        $arr = explode(' ',trim($parameter));
        $firstparameter = $arr[0];

        $linkService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(LinkService::class);
        $linkDetails = $linkService->resolve($firstparameter);

        return $linkDetails['type'];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$linkService = $this->objectManager->get(LinkService::class);
$result = $linkService->resolve($linkValue);
```

That could help you in a custom ViewHelper

Possible Values for `$linkValue`:

- `t3://page?uid=1` => [string (pageuid), 'page']
- `info@example.com` => [string (email), 'email']
- `https://typo3.org` => [string (url), 'url']
- `t3://file?uid=226` => [TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File, 'file']

`$result` returns an array. Every case has the argument "type". Depending on the type, another value or object is returned. I have listed this above.

The class is available from TYPO3 Version 8.

Comment: Could you please add some examples for possible `$linkValue` and their according output in `$result`? Thx

Comment: If the $linkValue is a file and have additional arguments like _blank, this code will call an exception. Example `t3://file?uid=226 _blank`. My workaround for this, is to explode trim the string and take the first item in the array

Answer (score 2):

You could also check the linktype with the vhs extension, e.g. to set a different target:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
...
<f:variable name="target">_self</f:variable> 
<v:condition.string.contains haystack="{url}" needle="t3://file?uid">
  <f:variable name="target">_blank</f:variable>         
</v:condition.string.contains>
<v:condition.string.contains haystack="{url}" needle="http">
  <f:variable name="target">_blank</f:variable>         
</v:condition.string.contains>
<v:condition.string.contains haystack="{url}" needle="www">
  <f:variable name="target">_blank</f:variable>
</v:condition.string.contains> 

<f:link.typolink parameter="{url}" target="{target}">the link</f:link.typolink>
```